# VLookup adding another column to the search

Tags: vba, excel

I am rather new to VBA and I am having trouble with a VLOOKUP code.

I have 3 sheets. Sheet2 (Supplier) contains the part number & supplier, Sheet 3 (Cost) contains the part number & cost. Sheet1 (Part Numbers) contains a standard part number list. The data in Sheets2 and 3 are updated regularly. I want the VBA to look for the part number (Sheet1.ColumnA) in the supplier list (Sheet2.ColumnA) and paste the supplier name (Sheet2.ColumnC) into Sheet1.ColumnB.  Once I figure out how to do this I will then modify the code to do similar with the cost and put it in Sheet1.ColumnC.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub Lookup()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Lr As Integer

Lr = Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last row

For i = 1 To Lr ' last row

Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2) = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Supplier'!A:C,3,0)"

  If i = "" Then Exit For

Next i

End Sub
```

When I execute this code the Sheet1.ColumnB populates (Taken from cell A)

```
"=VLOOKUP(A2,'Supplier'!A:B:B,3,0)"
```

Can anyone tell me Why is it showing A:B:B when I enter A:C?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `If i = "" Then Exit For`? Seems like it will never do anything. The condition should never come back true.

Comment: Thanks. I've read a lot of feeds on coding and it's probably something I picked up without understanding it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding has always been that mixing R1C1 and A1 notations is risky and likely to produce unexpected and undesirable results as Excel decides how to interpret the formula. Try the following:

```
Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2) = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Supplier'!C1:C3,3,0)"
```

Or:

```
Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2) = "=VLOOKUP(A" & (i + 1) & ",'Supplier'!A:C,3,0)"
```

In this particular case, I would probably go with the latter method just because C1:C3 is a little confusing at a glance as to whether it is A1 or R1C1 notation. If you aren't always looking up based on column A, you could determine the column letter from the column index with a small conversion method.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I also managed to get it to work with a code as follows, "Worksheets("Part Numbers").Cells(i + 1, 2) = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Supplier'!C[-2]:C[1],3,0)" As you can see its quite messy and confusing.  I have replaced it with the one you have provided as it is easier to follow.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Kel For the record, on your equation, if you were trying to convert A:C into relative R1C1 when the formula is in column C, you would need C[-2]:C NOT C[-2]:C[1] which translates to A:D. In this case, VLOOKUP doesn't care that you added a column so it really doesn't matter. Now I will suggest you be careful using relative references to other worksheets. Just mentioning all of this for future reference.